# python dictionary (unordered selections key)

Tags: python, dictionary, unordered

I have a question about dic.has_key

my code is

```
def insertToDic(dic,comSick):
    for datum in comSick :
            if dic.has_key(datum):
                    dic[datum]+=1
            else :
                    dic[datum] =1
```

if comSick is

```
comSick=[(A,B),(A,C),(B,A)]
```

dic will be

```
dic = {(A,B) : 1, (A,C) : 1, (B,A) : 1}
```

but what I want is unordered key (which means (A,B) = (B,A))

```
dic = {(A,B) : 2, (A,C) : 1}  <-- this is what I want
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def insertToDic(dic,comSick):
    for datum in comSick :
        sorted_datum = tuple(sorted(datum))
        dic[sorted_datum] = dic.get(sorted_datum, 0) + 1

comSick=[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A')]

dic = {}
insertToDic(dic, comSick)
print(dic)
```

I made some changes. I sorted the datum before updating the dictionary. This ensures that one of `(A,B)` and `(B,A)` will be changed to the other. It is not clear what `A` and `B` are, so `B` may be lower than `A`. Did you mean the strings `'A'` and `'B'`? That's what I used.

I also changed how you increment the value. The `get()` method will return the current value if it exists or the given default value if it doesn't--in this case, zero.

Also note that the final dictionary has no inherent order, so you may get the answer `{('A', 'C'): 1, ('A', 'B'): 2}`, which is what I got in my Python 3.5.2 in Anaconda.

Comment: `turple(sorted(datum))` will return `('A', 'B')`, so as @Rory asked, are the tuple key/value pairs characters?

Comment: @d3r1ck The tuple key/value pairs are characters :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

frozenset(('A', 'B'))

as the key.